# Create a group and send out emails when each order comes to an email id assigned for each group

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a requirement which is like follows:
We have a B2B model store

I have a store in which we want to set up groups with clients from different places and assign an email id for each group. Now once there is an order from one group, a notification should be sent to the assigned email id of the group. This assigned email is of the distributor.

Let me explain this in another way if you didn't get it.
We have 6 clients from 3 different places.
place1: client1, client2
place2: client3, client4
place3: client5, client6

email ids: Place1id@store.com, Place2id@store.com, Place3id@store.com

Now if client2 places an order, Place1id@store.com should get an email notification. 
If client6 places an order, Place3id@store.com should get an email notification.
And so on.

Is there anyway we could achieve that without having to create multiple stores?

Answer (score 1):

You could use customer groups feature and assign users to groups.  Then use a follow up email extension like aheadworks module to send an email to a specific group id email when order is placed .  With their module you can send a copy to a specified email, and set send to customer to "no"

Should meet your needs exactly.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Now I get the idea. Is there anyway to get the customer locations as they sign up? For example it would be helpful if the user can set the address as they sign up.

Comment: For what reason? Marketing, shipping address, drop ship address?

Comment: We need to create customer groups for based on the locations(districts) for sending out order details to the district head of the business!

Comment: Can't you just collect that when they check out?

Comment: No we need to create the customer group as they sign up. There is someway to activate the address input form in the register page. I am not just finding the technique.

Comment: Please try this extension https://amasty.com/customer-attributes.html. It's not available by default.  There might be free alternatives, bit this one is reputable.